# How to protect Web API called by IdentityServer4

Tags: identityserver4, asp.net-core-webapi

I make multiple calls to a Web API during login operations in IdentityServer4. Same applies during password reset operations which is custom code I have added to the IdentityServer4 project.

So how should I protect my ASP.NET Core Web API when the user isn't yet authenticated via OIDC which implies that there also isn't exist any access token at that stage. I would like to only allow IdentityServer4 to call these Web API methods instead of running unprotected Web API's.

Any suggestions?

Comment: why would you want IdentityServer4 to call your API methods?

Comment: As I mentioned there are multiple Web API calls I need to make during logon and password reset operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this

https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/topics/tools.html

to generate your own tokens to call the APIs.

Comment: See this blog for more information on how to use the IdentityServerTools class. https://www.strathweb.com/2017/10/self-issuing-an-identityserver4-token-in-an-identityserver4-service/