# How can I call a protected API from IdentityServer4?

Tags: identityserver4

I want to split email service from identity server project by calling separate api that is authenticated by IS.

My problem is to call api from identity server. Currently I have additional 'fake' client inside IdentityServer that is calling the api.

Here is the standard option with Client Credential Flow.

1. Get token
2. Return token
3. Call api
4. Check token
5. Return data

[image: Standard Client Credential Flow]
But I want to omit the client. So the IdentityServer is the client.
I have created a 'fake' client inside IS and I think that it is wrong way to do it?

MessageService.cs inside IdentityServer

```
 // Authenticating the fake client
 var disco = await DiscoveryClient.GetAsync("http://localhost:5000");
 var tokenClient = new TokenClient(disco.TokenEndpoint, "MailApiClient", "secret");
 var tokenResponse = await tokenClient.RequestClientCredentialsAsync("EmailScope");
 // Setting the token
 client.SetBearerToken(tokenResponse.AccessToken);
 var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(someMailModel));
 // Posting to api
 var response = await client.PostAsync(_emailSettings.RequestUri, content).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

[image: client inside IS]

The fake client authenticates with the IS and then sends the message with token to mailapi.
Rather creating fake client inside IS I want the IS to be client itself. So the IdentityServer will call api without middleware client.

Also in the future some other client will use the MailApi.

Comment: Why do you want to call MailApi from IDS4? if at all there is a business reason for it, can't you inject ITokenService or any other service that is responsible to create the token directly into the class that calls MailAPI? instead of the doing the self network call?

Comment: I can see the need for this. A good example is if you put your User Claims in an API and you wanted to expose that API to many other APIs and IdentityServer4 to get the data.

Comment: I think your question is more like "How can I call a protected API from IdentityServer4?"

Comment: @Gokulnath Currently I have no need for exposing the api to others, but in 'near' future I want to expose the mailing api to my javascript client which will need to have some authorization (only the IS and the client will be able to use it). I'm looking for creating token myself (omitting the additional fake client) with ITokenService, looks a bit hard but will try to do it.

Comment: @aaronR Oh that title is a bit more simple and obvious, thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a class "IdentityServerTools" which gives ability to manually issue token inside IdentityServer.

[How to protect Web API called by IdentityServer4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46084139/how-to-protect-web-api-called-by-identityserver4?rq=1)
https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/topics/tools.html